Smart pointer in map of class?
I am trying to insert objects in a map, I was recommended to use pointer, so here is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class Person
{
private:
    int m_age;
    std::string m_name;

public:
    Person(int age, std::string name):
    m_age(age),
    m_name(name)
    {
        
    };
    
    void PrintPerson()
    {
        std::cout << "name: " << m_name << "\n";
        std::cout << "age: " << m_age << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<size_t, Person*> person_map;
    
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        person_map.insert(std::make_pair(n, new Person(n, std::to_string(n))));
    }
    
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        person_map.at(n)->PrintPerson();
    }
    return 0;
}

My questions is I have a new in my code, but I don't see delete. Would this code cause memory leak? If it does, can I use smart pointer to prevent that? Or what should be the proper way to manage this implementation? Thank you.

Yes, a new without a delete will leak. But why were you recommended to use a pointer?!  The easiest solution is to not use pointers, and not use new.

I am trying to insert objects in a map -- But that is not what you ended up doing.  You are storing pointers into the map.  If you wanted to store objects, the map would have been std::map<size_t, Person> person_map.

@PaulMcKenzie Perhaps OP means "object" in the OOP sense, not in the C++ language lawyer sense?

Just use : std::map<size_t, Person>. That's what containers are for : storing objects. Rely on move semantics to keep things (reasonably) performant.

"I was recommended to use pointer..." That was a bad recommendation. Ditch/leave whichever course/teacher you're learning c++ from. Here there is no need to use pointers. And if there were, you could use smart pointers.


Would this code cause memory leak?

Yes

can I use smart pointer to prevent that?

Yes, but for the example you gave, you don't need a pointer at all.
int main()
{
    std::map<size_t, Person> person_map;
    
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        person_map.emplace(n, Person(n, std::to_string(n)));
    }
    
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        person_map.at(n).PrintPerson();
    }
    return 0;
}

If you do need pointers (e.g. Person has virtual methods, and you instead fill person_map with instances that are subclasses of Person), you should use std::unique_ptr by default.
int main()
{
    std::map<size_t, std::unique_ptr<Person>> person_map;
    
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        person_map.emplace(n, std::make_unique<Person>(n, std::to_string(n)));
    }
    
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        person_map.at(n)->PrintPerson();
    }
    return 0;
}

